# Can stars bend light?

Tags: curvature, stars, gravitational-lensing

Is it possible for a star to be so big that its gravity can bend light like a black hole? If so, would the star appear dark or bright, or would it collapse on itself?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_experiment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes stars can bend light with the immensity of their gravitational fields. A good example of this phenomenon being put to good use is in the historical incidence of the first major verification of Einstein's theory of General relativity, which of course predicts the phenomenon in the first place.

In 1919, the famous astronomer Arthur Eddington, verified that the bending of starlight occurred to the degree predicted by Einstein's theory by observing the light from *occulted* stars during an ordinary solar eclipse, thus Eddington witnessed the gravitational field of our own sun bending star light!

There is nothing really special or odd about the gravity of black holes save from the fact that the fields are unusually strong, however, ignoring rotation, charge, and the cosmological constant; the solutions of Einstein's equation that describe the gravity around a spherical black hole are entirely similar to the description of the fields around stars, i.e. the curved space-time around spherically symmetric massive bodies is that described by the Schwarzschild metric. Ordinary stars, however, are not massive enough to have an external "event horizon" or point of no return from which nothing can escape, hence their light is able to shine out into surrounding space.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Our own sun is big enough to bend starlight, an experimental fact that proved the correctness of Einstein's formulation of general relativity over 100 years ago. The effect was tiny (not visible to the naked eye) but measurable with telescopes.

Comment: thank you for the answer